# Web API works fine on local but returning 501 on server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using `WebAPI2`. This is my controller Class:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{     
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoginMethod()
    {      
     HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "This is a simple message");
     return response;
    }
}
```

I am able to test this method locally from postman and it is giving me proper output but on server it fails. This method is inside `ValuesController` and I am calling by this way(on local)

```
http://localhost:49476/api/values/LoginMethod/
```

and it is running without a problem. On server I'm calling by this way

```
http://example.com/api/values/LoginMethod/
```

It is giving me error with status code `500 internal server error`:

```
 {
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: nameValueCollection",
  "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentNullException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
 }
```

This is my `WebAPIConfig` file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Why make it a post call?  As it’s not writing to anything just change it to httpget.  Not sure if that will make any difference but worth trying

Comment: @Hursey When I changed it to `HttpGet` and testing it on postman with `get` it gives me error as `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'`.

Comment: Did you change the decoration on the controller loginmethod?

Comment: @Hursey Yes, I did.

Comment: I would try something else first. when you work locally, you probably use IIS Express.. When you deploy somewhere you use a proper IIS. Change your local project to use IIS as well and try again. any issues you see in production, you should be able to replicate on your development machine as well